# Rollback is not working with spring declarative

Tags: spring

I'm working with spring declarative approach to rollback transaction on any exceptions with in the method. This method had multiple DAO calls[1,2,3..] and those needs to be maintained in a single transaction. So i'm trying to acheive if any exceptions comes in DAO call[3], then spring has to rollback preceeding DAO calls. i.e[1,2]

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, readOnly = true,rollbackFor=java.lang.Throwable.class)
    public void processWorkflowActionsInOneTransaction(...) throws Exception {

// DAO call 1 here....

// DAO call 2 here....

// DAO call 3 here....[throw exception]

}

The above configuration created a single transaction for the mentioned method, but it is not triggered rollback after exception. I have attached spring logs for the better understanding. Please help me if any one had a similar issue.
[Spring logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyPGT.png)

Comment: Are you inserting/updating any data in the dao call 1,2 or 3 and still seeing the data getting persisted in the database even after exception? Can you show us some code on h0w are you injecting daos and DB resources (jdbcTemplate/entityManager etc)

Comment: <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">

Comment: There are inserts as well as updates in the DAO calls and i'm getting session using HibernateSessionManager.currentSession(sessionFactory); for each DAO, here sessionFactory object is injected to each DAO saperately.        

<bean id="sessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" scope="singleton">